# python marshmallow to take fields.Int() or fields.Str()

Tags: python, string, int, marshmallow

I am receiving data from another source that sometimes sends an int, and sometimes a string for a given variable: location. 
For example, they will 1, or 2, or 3 for ints or they will send "building" or "car" or "bus" as an example.

I tried

```
location = fields.Int(allow_string=True, strict=False)
```

which gives the following error

> marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'status': ['Not a valid
>   integer.']}

and

```
location = fields.Str(allow_int=True, strict=False)
```

which gives the following error

> marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'status': ['Not a valid
>   string.']}

but they both do not work for both types. Is there a way to accept both types: strings and ints?

Comment: Question unclear.  Do you need to handle any string, or only strings that represent integers e.g. "123"?  Do you want the validated data to actually be string or integer?

Comment: @wim I gave more info in my question. It's basically either an actual number: 1 or 2 or 3, or a string: "car", "bus" or "building". So I need to be able to receive both.

Comment: Then don't use a schema validation. The whole point of it is to be strict, not airy-fairy, seems like marshmallow is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: may be you could try custom fields. https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/custom_fields.html#creating-a-field-class

Answer (score -1):

[Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io)'s `fields.Number` (from which `fields.Integer`, `fields.Float` and `field.Decimal` inherit) will happily accept a valid "castable" string.

This means you can optionally pass an integer or string to them without issue. However if casting fails, you will face an exception.

```
class MySchema(Schema):
     foo = fields.Integer()

MySchema().load({"foo": "123"})
# prints {"foo": 123}

MySchema().load({"foo": 456})
# prints {"foo": 456}

MySchema().load({"foo": "bar"})
# marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'foo': ['Not a valid integer.']}
```

On the contrary, `fields.String` will not accept any integer.

```
class MySchema(Schema):
     foo = fields.Integer()

MySchema().load({"foo": "bar"})
# prints {"foo": "bar}

MySchema().load({"foo": 123})
# marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'foo': ['Not a valid string.']}
```

If your input is either an integer or a string containing an integer you can use `fields.Integer` to parse them.

If this is something more random, you'll need to use [custom fields](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/custom_fields.html#creating-a-field-class) as mentioned by @shihe zhang and customize `_deserialize` and `_serialize` to deal with your data.

Comment: I got my solution from your answer's phrase "If your input is either an integer or a string containing an integer you can use fields.Integer to parse them." Thanks @Antwan